# Using Regex to replace parts of a string in python

Tags: python, regex

I have this situation where I thave strings like `1k`, `300k`, `500k_cleaned and replaced`, etc.

I wish to use regex package to replace `k` with `000` and delete the rest of the characters.

My code always throws errors:

```
renamed=re.sub(r"\b[k]\b",'000',df_VSS[i][0])
```

This is the line of code I have and I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `_` and digits are word chars, so there is no word boundary between `k` and `_` and between `1` and `k`.

You can match `k` in between a digit and a character other than an alphanumeric char:

```py
import re
text = '1k, 300k, 500k_cleaned and replaced'
print( re.sub(r'(?<=\d)k(?![^\W_])', '000', text) )
# => 1000, 300000, 500000_cleaned and replaced
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/iF3qTT) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HM0hdq/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<=\d)` - a positive lookbehind that requires a digit to appear immediately on the left
- `k` - a `k` letter
- `(?![^\W_])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a char other than a non-word or underscore char immediately on the right (it is a `\b` with `_` subtracted from it).

Answer (score 1):

If you have only to deal with the problem you described, a (maybe) simpler solution could be to use

```
s = my_str.split("k")[0] # get everything before k
s += "000"
```

Regexes can be tricky so I would advise you to use it only if no easier solution has been found. Also, if you use regexes, the website https://regex101.com/ can come in handy